# HTML5 video player gallery with ogg fallback

Tags: javascript, video, ogg, video-player

I have created a simple video gallery on my page which consists of 4 videos as thumbnails and 1 player which played the clicked thumbnail.

I have wrote some javascript which allows the user to click a thumbnail which triggers a function. The function then loads the new video SRC into the `<video>` player. Now this works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox as its in a mp4 format. I thought a simple change of the mp4 to ogg type would make this work for both. But it doesn't.

How to get the following JS working so that all browsers have ogg and mp4 support.

Heres what I have created:

```js
var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
var oggVid = document.getElementById('oggSource');

function germanicosLoadVid() {
  player.pause();
  player.pause();
  mp4Vid.setAttribute('src', "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4");
  oggVid.setAttribute('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
  player.load();
  player.play();
}

function platinumLoadVid() {
  player.pause();
  mp4Vid.setAttribute('src', "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4");
  oggVid.setAttribute('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
  player.load();
  player.play();
}

function houseLoadVid() {
  player.pause();
  mp4Vid.setAttribute('src', "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4");
  oggVid.setAttribute('src', "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv");
  player.load();
  player.play();
}
```

```html
<video controls class="vid-center" id="videoPlayer" style="max-width:800px;">
    <source src="<?php the_field('video_file_1'); ?>" type="video/mp4"  id="mp4Source">
    <source id="oggSource" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.o" type="video/ogg"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag. 
    </video>

<img src="http://getuikit.com/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" alt="" onclick="houseLoadVid()" />
<img src="http://getuikit.com/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" alt="" onclick="platinumLoadVid()" />
<img src="http://getuikit.com/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" alt="" onclick="germanicosLoadVid()" />
```

Theres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40u93ner/4/) here, too.

Comment: Use .webm for Firefox. Also the ogg `src` extension is `.o` change that to  `.ogv`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v2r20vd9 with webm tested in Chrome and Firefox PC